# Random Forest: Predictors have more than 53 categories?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

What is the solution when we want to apply the Random Forest function in R to a predictor with more than 53 categories?

```
> RandomForestPrediction=function(alpha){
+   d = sort(sample(nrow(MPS), nrow(MPS)*alpha))
+   train<-MPS[d,]
+   test<-MPS[-d,]
+   myNtree=1000
+   myMtry=5
+   myImportance=TRUE
+   mod2 = randomForest(factor(m.Decision)~.,data=train,tree=myNtree,mtry=myMtry,importance=myImportance)
+   fitted=predict(mod2,test,type="response")
+   return(table(fitted,test$m.Decision))
+ }
> RandomForestPrediction(0.7)
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
Can not handle categorical predictors with more than 53 categories.
```

Comment: Do you actually have a categorical variable with more than 53 categories/levels? Maybe a numerical variable was converted into a factor variable? Inspect the dataset using `str(MPS)` to identify the variable that causes the problem. If you really have a categorical variable with more than 53 levels, you just cant use the `randomForest` function, I'm afraid.

Comment: It's exactly the categorical variable, because I'm applying the Random Forest to the data set from the customers. And one predictor is Occupation with 73 levels. I can not take this variable down because it's known as a valuable predictor!

Comment: Another possibility is to recode the 73 levels into binary dummy variables. Or maybe group the 73 occupations into smaller categories. Other than that, it is simply a limitation of the code of `randomForest`. Maybe there are other implementations of random forests in R that don't have that limitation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[In this youtube video](https://youtu.be/kwt6XEh7U3g?t=44m32s), Jeremy Howard explains his technique to deal with this problem in [r](/questions/tagged/r), he separates the variables in two sets according the number of observations for each level :

- Set 1 : levels for $N_{obs}>100$ or ( $25<N_{obs}<100$ + predictive value)
- Set 2 : all the rest.

I should mention that I'm new to Random Forest and the luck has just made that I looked at this video two days ago. And even if this technique makes sense to me (separate in two sets with different importance) I can't explain the choice of these thresholds (which are obviously a bit arbitrary and dataset dependent), and at what point one can consider that a level has a honorable predictive value.

Comment: How can you actually identify those variables with more than 53 levels? I have many columns and str(dataframe) only gives me back the name of the columns. Thank you!